# How to to highlight some of the choices of radioButtons based on a checkboxInput in an R shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

### Context

Here is the structure of my app:

- Two navigation panels named "All" and "Driver".
- "All" panel contains a "New Event" button. When the "New Event" button is clicked, the user is prompted to enter an event name and
  submit it. Upon clicking submit, a new tab is created within "All"
  panel.
- The newly created tab contains a `checkboxInput`.
- A user can create as many events as they want in the "All" panel.
- The "Driver" panel then shows all the event names i.e., the user entered tab names as `radioButtons` choices.

Here's a quick demo:

[image]

**Question**: If a user has checked the `checkboxInput` in some of the created tabs, how do I make only those tab names in "Driver" panel bold while keeping others plain? In the attached example, I want to make "Event2" choice bold under the "Driver" tab

#### Code

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_fluid(

  nav_panel(
    title = "Day1",
    navset_card_pill(
      nav_panel(title = "All",
                tagList(
                  br(),
                  # Button to launch a new event modal where the user provides the event name.
                  actionButton("add", "New Event"),
                  br(),
                  # br(),
                  # A panel of tabs. Each tab corresponds to one event.
                  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs")
                )),
      nav_panel(
        title = "Driver",
        uiOutput("event_of_interest_ui")
      )
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # When the 'New Event' button is clicked, a modal pops up asking for event name.
  observeEvent(input$add, {

    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        textInput(
          inputId = "event_name",
          label = "Event name:",
          value = ""
        ),
        actionButton("submit_event_name", "Submit"),
        title = "Enter event name",
        footer = NULL,
        size = "s",
        easyClose = FALSE
      )
    )

  })


  # Initialize a vector of all event names
  all_events <- reactiveValues(namez = NULL)


  # Event name and IDs
  event_name   <- reactive(input$event_name) # specified by user
  tab_name     <- reactive(paste0("tab_", gsub("\\s", "", event_name())))
  text_area_id <- reactive(paste0(tab_name(), "_comments")) # id of text box
  save_btn_id  <- reactive(paste0(tab_name(), "_save"))



  observeEvent(input$submit_event_name, {

    # Remove the modal dialog
    removeModal()

    # New tab is inserted in the existing tabset panel with ID 'tabs'
    insertTab(
      inputId = "tabs",
      tabPanel(
        title = event_name(),

          # Option to highlight
          checkboxInput(
            inputId = paste0(tab_name(), "_check"),
            label = p("Highlight this event for later discussion"),
            width = "600px"
          )

      )
    )
    # Update event names vector as new events are created
    all_events$namez <- c(all_events$namez, event_name())

  })


  output$event_of_interest_ui <- renderUI({
    if (!is.null( all_events$namez)){

      radioButtons(
        inputId = "event_select",
        label = h4("Select event of interest:"),
        choices = all_events$namez,
        selected = character(0),
        width = 500
      )
    } else {
      h4("Please create at least 1 event on the 'All Events' page.")
    }
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the examples in the docs (`?radioButtons`) you can style the labels for the radio buttons items using HTML and the `choicesValues/Names` arguments instead of `choices`. What remains is to use e.g. a `lapply` to conditionally wrap the checked event names in a `<b>` tag. In the code below I also added a red text color:

```
output$event_of_interest_ui <- renderUI({
  if (!is.null(all_events$namez)) {
    choiceValues <- all_events$namez
    choiceNames <- lapply(
      all_events$namez,
      \(x) {
        input_id <- paste0("tab_", gsub("\\s", "", x), "_check")
        if (input[[input_id]]) {
          HTML(paste0("<b style='color:red;'>", x, "</b>"))
        } else {
          x
        }
      }
    )

    radioButtons(
      inputId = "event_select",
      label = h4("Select event of interest:"),
      choiceValues = choiceValues,
      choiceNames = choiceNames,
      selected = character(0),
      width = 500
    )
  } else {
    h4("Please create at least 1 event on the 'All Events' page.")
  }
})
```

[image]